# Spring MVC serving same static content for all urls matching a pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC 4 application, I want to serve all URLs under "/editor/**" with the same "/editor/index.html" resource.

I am using EmberJS with History API, so a request like /editor/task/1 is not really a URL its merely a history URL that should be sent to /editor/index.html and it will handle it.

I tried using

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/editor/**" location="/editor/"/>
```

but this don't work, it sends subsequent URLs like "/editor/task/1" to the servlet and of course it sends a 404 resource not found.

is there a way to serve all the urls with the same resource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a controller which returns the same view for all urls matching "/editor/*".

```
@Controller
public class EditorController {
  @RequestMapping("/editor/*")
  @GET
  public String doGet() {
    return "editor/index.html";
}
```

Comment: what view resolver should I use for this? what view resolver would serve html files ?

Comment: I believe you can use a static resource definition to server your static html files as follows <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/" />. You may need to modify the name of the resources so you don't get a clash with the controller mapping.